Compactification of complex sphere
Consider the affine complex sphere: $Spec \ \frac{\mathbb{C}[x, y, z]}{(x^2+y^2+z^2-1)}$. By change of coordinates it is isomorphic to $Spec \ \frac{\mathbb{C}[x, y, z]}{(xy-z(1-z))}$. I was looking for its compactification. Its compactification in $\mathbb{P}^3$ is given by $\mathcal{Z}(xy-z(w-z))$. But I can not identify this projective variety. I have seen in some paper that it is $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ and the complex sphere is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1 \setminus \Delta$ ($\Delta$ is the diagonal). But I cannot find explicit isomorphism. Can anybody help?
Thanks in advance.

Do you mean projectivization rather than compactification (it is not its compactification in the strong topology, and it is already pre-compact as an affine scheme).

I mean projectivization.

One can make a linear change of coordinates $X=x, Y=y, Z=z, W= w-z$. The equation becomes $XY-ZW= 0$, and  it defines the image of the Segre embedding of the product of two projective lines with coordinates $(x_0:x_1), (y_0:y_1) $ given by $X=x_0y_0, Y=x_1y_1, Z=x_0y_1, W=x_1y_0$. The affine sphere is given by the complement to the vanishing set $0=w=Z+W$, that is, $x_0y_1 = -x_1y_0$. If we change the coordinate $x_1$ to $-x_1$, then it becomes the equation $X_0Y_1=X_1Y_0$ of the diagonal.
Added: for the last fact, note that the product of two projective lines is the set of ordered pairs of points on $\mathbb P^1$ and the diagonal corresponds to coinciding points. The points $(X_0:X_1)$ and $(Y_0:Y_1)$ coincide if and only if the vectors $(X_0,X_1)$ and $(Y_0,Y_1)$ are proportional, if and only if the $2\times 2$ matrix formed by them has the zero determinant.
